# Error raised while template file found in post-mortem

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I found a lot of similar questions, but none answered to my problem.
Everything seems to be well configured in *settings.py*. The concerned template displays without any problem, but as soon as i add the following line:

```
 {% include "{{ STATIC_URL }}angular-modules/register/register.html" %}
```

Django raises a TemplateDoesNotExist error, i checked the content of the path it seems to be right.
The postmortem show the following:

```
Django tried loading these templates, in this order:
Using loader django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader:
C:\Users\Dah'\workOnPython\dynlocal_tpape\Dynlocal\templates\contrib.html (File exists)
Using loader django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader:
C:\Users\Dah'\workOnPython\dynlocal_tpape\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\templates\contrib.html (File does not exist)
C:\Users\Dah'\workOnPython\dynlocal_tpape\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\templates\contrib.html (File does not exist)
```

Please notice that the loader finds the file but doesn't display it.

here is the lines of views.py that are concerned:

```
def contrib(request):
    user_form = UserForm()
    return render_to_response('contrib.html',{'user_form':user_form},RequestContext(request))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the "{{ STATIC_URL }}" from your include:

```
{% include "angular-modules/register/register.html" %}
```

`{{ STATIC_URL }}` is for serving static files - not for looking up templates -, and in this context (a litteral string passed as argument to a templatetag) wil NOT be treated as a variable anyway.